# maximum file upload size in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, c#-3.0

I use the following method to upload a document into sharepoint document library.
However, upon executing the query - get the following error:
Message = "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

the files are failing over 1mb, so i tested it via the sharepoint UI and the same file uploaded successfully.

any thoughts on what's the issue is? is it possible to stream the file over rather than 1 large file chunk? the file in question is only 3mb in size..

```
private ListItem UploadDocumentToSharePoint(RequestedDocumentFileInfo requestedDoc, ClientContext clientContext)
{
    try
    {
        var uploadLocation = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", SiteUrl, Helpers.ListNames.RequestedDocuments,
                                           Path.GetFileName(requestedDoc.DocumentWithFilePath));

        //Get Document List
        var documentslist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Helpers.ListNames.RequestedDocuments);
        var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation
                                          {
                                              Content = requestedDoc.ByteArray,
                                              Overwrite = true,
                                              Url = uploadLocation //Upload URL,
                                          };

        var uploadFile = documentslist.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
        clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
        item["Title"] = requestedDoc.FileNameParts.FileSubject;
        item["FileLeafRef"] = requestedDoc.SharepointFileName;
        item.Update();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(exception.Message);
    }
    return GetDocument(requestedDoc.SharepointFileName + "." + requestedDoc.FileNameParts.Extention, clientContext);
}
```

EDIT: i did find the following ms page regarding my issue (which seems identical to the issue they have raised) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2529243 but appears to not provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok found the solution here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

i'll need to store the document on the server hosting the file then using the filestream upload process i've done in my code below:

```
    private ListItem UploadDocumentToSharePoint(RequestedDocumentFileInfo requestedDoc, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        try
        {
            using(var fs = new FileStream(string.Format(@"C:\[myfilepath]\{0}", Path.GetFileName(requestedDoc.DocumentWithFilePath)), FileMode.Open))
            {
                File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, string.Format("/{0}/{1}", Helpers.ListNames.RequestedDocuments, requestedDoc.FileName), fs, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(exception.Message);
        }
        return GetDocument(requestedDoc.SharepointFileName + "." + requestedDoc.FileNameParts.Extention, clientContext);
    }
```