# Upload > 5 MB files to sharepoint 2013 programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am having troubles uploading large files to my sharepoint 2013/office 365 site. I am using Visual Stuidos 2010 and .NET 4.0

I have tried code from these questions:

[SP2010 Client Object Model 3 MB limit - updating maxReceivedMessageSize doesnt get applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600464/sp2010-client-object-model-3-mb-limit-updating-maxreceivedmessagesize-doesnt-g)

[maximum file upload size in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491696/maximum-file-upload-size-in-sharepoint)

[Upload large files 100mb+ to Sharepoint 2010 via c# Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300550/upload-large-files-100mb-to-sharepoint-2010-via-c-sharp-web-service)

[How to download/upload files from/to SharePoint 2013 using CSOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom)

But nothing is working. So I need a little help. Here is code that I have tried:

1: ( I have also tried to use `SharePointOnlineCredentials` instead of `NetworkCredential` for this one)

```
#region 403 forbidden

byte[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
System.Net.WebClient webclient = new System.Net.WebClient();
System.Uri uri = new Uri(sharePointSite + directory + fileInfo.Name);
webclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password.ToString(), sharePointSite + "Documents");

webclient.UploadData(uri, "PUT", content);

#endregion
```

2:

```
#region 500 Internal Server Error


using (var fs = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open))
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(
        context, 
        web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + directory, 
        fs, 
        true);
}

#endregion
```

I have gotten smaller file uploads to work with:

```
#region File upload for smaller files

Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + directory);
web.Context.Load(folder);
context.ExecuteQuery();

FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();

fci.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);

fciURL = sharePointSite + directory;
fciURL += (fciURL[fciURL.Length - 1] == '/') ? fileInfo.Name : "/" + fileInfo.Name;

fci.Url = fciURL;
fci.Overwrite = true;

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCollection documentfiles = folder.Files;
context.Load(documentfiles);
context.ExecuteQuery();

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = documentfiles.Add(fci);
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery();

#endregion
```

My Using Statement:

```
using (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(sharePointSite))
{
    //string fciURL = "";
    exception = "";
    context.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, password);


    Web web = context.Web;
    web.Context.Credentials = context.Credentials;


    if (!web.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl"))
    {
        web.Context.Load(web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);
        web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    //upload large file
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I went with:

```
MemoryStream destStream;

using (System.IO.FileStream fInfo = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open))
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    byte[] byteArr;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = fInfo.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        byteArr = ms.ToArray();
    }

    destStream = new MemoryStream(byteArr);

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(
        context,
        serverRelativeURL + directory + fileInfo.Name,
        destStream,
        true);

    context.ExecuteQuery();
    results = "File Uploaded";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call the `context.ExecuteQuery()` method.

Comment: I believe you should remove all MemoryStream related methods and put `fInfo` stream to the `SaveBinaryDirect()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code snippet number 2 is that you missed a file name:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open))
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(
        context, 
        serverRelativeURL + directory + fs.Name,
                                        ^^^^^^^^
        fs, 
        true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My research on the subject showed that using the [FrontPage Remote Control Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442469(v=office.14).aspx) was the most adventageous way of reliably uploading large files.

This is because FrontPage RPC supports file fragmentation, which helps avoid `OutOfMemomory` exceptions due to Windows needing to allocate the entire file to continuous memory.

It also supports sending meta data, useful it pretty much any file upload application. One major advantage of this is that you can actually specify the correct content type without a user having to log in and change it later. (with all other methods I tried it would just be set as the default type.)

[See my answer on the Sharepoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/41550/7175) for further detail on implementing Frontpage RPC.